# What are submodules and how are they used?

Tags: fortran

I don't quite understand the purpose of submodules. I know there's very little support for them in most compilers but the concept is interesting. I think I understand the basic concept but all the examples I've seen (Fortran Wiki, Modern Fortran Explained, the technical report) are simplistic, use exactly the same example (`point` type all within the same file) and don't show their actual use when calling the function. In what situations would you want to use submodules? When you want to use a submodule do you include a use statement? I'd really like if someone could provide an example.

Comment: I'll put some more stuff (including examples) on the Fortran wiki over the next week or two.

Comment: Also, if you have the technical report or standard, look at the example in appendix C.

Comment: Submodules are a Fortran 2008 feature. It would be nice is someone with enough reputation points created a "fortran2008" tag. There are already fortran77, fortran90, fortran95, and fortran2003 tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simple answer is that you put code into submodules when you want to have less code in the parent module or submodule.

You might want to have less source code in the parent module or submodule because the source code for the parent is getting too long.

Before submodules, the only way this could be done was to move source code out of the module into a different module or external procedure.  But this wasn't always possible if the source code to be moved referenced PRIVATE things or components that were to remain in the original module.  Submodules can access the things declared in their parent module or submodule by host association - the source code can still access PRIVATE things in the same way that it could if it was still part of the physical source code of the parent.

You might also want to split source code out of the parent module in order to avoid compilation cascades, if relevant to your processor.  Changes to a module typically require recompilation of that module (and its descendants), and then recompilation of all program units that use that module (and their descendants), repeatedly cascading to further recompilation where any recompiled program units are themselves modules.  Changes to a submodule typically only require recompilation of that submodule and any of its descendant submodules.

The hierarchical nature of submodules may also suit a hierarchical code arrangement - where you do not want siblings at the same level of the hierarchy to be able to directly access the entities and procedures that they define.

The USE statement is only used where you want to access things in a scope that are provided by a module.  You cannot "use" a submodule in a USE statement (though a procedure with its INTERFACE defined in a module may have its body defined in a submodule).

A submodule of a module does not USE the parent module (it cannot - that is a bit like a module trying to USE itself) and it doesn't need to - it already has access to the things in the module by host association.  The submodule statement that starts a submodule program unit identifies the module (and perhaps another submodule) that it extends.  There is nothing in the source of a module proper that tells it how many submodules there may be extending it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The part I'm most interested in and what compelled me to ask this question was in regards to accessing a derived-type's parent's private data and procedures without creating monolithic modules that contain all your derived types. So in order to use the procedures contained within a sub-module you just have to USE the module that it extends(for lack of a better word) and it's like it's all in that single mdoule?

Comment: The module itself has the separate interface body for the procedure that you want to call.  The subprogram that defines the procedure can then be in a submodule.  Anything that then USE's the module (or is a descendant of the module) can then reference the procedure.