# Fortran error #5082: Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER when expecting one of: <END-OF-STATEMENT> ;

Tags: makefile, fortran

I am "making" a code.

The compilation with `make` fails producing this error

```
mpif90 -mkl -O3 -no-prec-div -fpp -openmp -xHost -DMPI -DEFTCOSMOMC -module ReleaseEFTMPI -IReleaseEFTMPI/ -c equations_EFT.f90 -o ReleaseEFTMPI/equations_EFT.o
equations_EFT.f90(267): error #5082: Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'EFTCAMBINITIALCONDITIONS' when expecting one of: <END-OF-STATEMENT> ;
        module subroutine EFTCAMBInitialConditions( y, EV, tau )
--------------------------^
equations_EFT.f90(267): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( % [ . = =>
        module subroutine EFTCAMBInitialConditions( y, EV, tau )
----------------------------------------------------------------^
equations_EFT.f90(271): error #6786: This is an invalid statement; an END [MODULE] statement is required.
        end subroutine EFTCAMBInitialConditions
--------^
equations_EFT.f90(271): error #6758: This name is invalid; if a name is present, it must match the corresponding interface body name.   [EFTCAMBINITIALCONDITIONS]
        end subroutine EFTCAMBInitialConditions
-----------------------^
equations_EFT.f90(268): error #6457: This derived type name has not been declared.   [EVOLUTIONVARS]
            type(EvolutionVars) EV
-----------------^
equations_EFT.f90(269): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [DL]
            real(dl) :: y(EV%nvar)
-----------------^
equations_EFT.f90(269): error #6535: This variable or component must be of a derived or structure type   [EV]
            real(dl) :: y(EV%nvar)
--------------------------^
equations_EFT.f90(269): error #6460: This is not a field name that is defined in the encompassing structure.   [NVAR]
            real(dl) :: y(EV%nvar)
-----------------------------^
equations_EFT.f90(269): error #6223: A specification expression is invalid.   [NVAR]
            real(dl) :: y(EV%nvar)
-----------------------------^
equations_EFT.f90(270): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [DL]
            real(dl) :: tau
-----------------^
equations_EFT.f90(269): error #6279: A specification expression object must be a dummy argument, a COMMON block object, or an object accessible through host or use association   [EV]
            real(dl) :: y(EV%nvar)
--------------------------^
compilation aborted for equations_EFT.f90 (code 1)
```

I attach the snippet from `equations_EFT.f90`

```
interface

        module subroutine EFTCAMBInitialConditions( y, EV, tau )
            type(EvolutionVars) EV
            real(dl) :: y(EV%nvar)
            real(dl) :: tau
        end subroutine EFTCAMBInitialConditions

    end interface
```

Is there something wrong in this snippet? It is strange because this is distributed software, but I have literally just followed the instruction to make the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of the question is an example of using [*submodules*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22825841/3157076), a feature newly introduced into Fortran in the 2008 revision.  To compile this code you will need a compiler which understands this concept.

The GNU and Intel compilers are examples of such, but you will need an appropriate version.

Comment: thanks. My version of gcc is 6.3.0, I was thinking that this was new enough to support the features you mentioned. Do you know of a more reliable version?

Comment: Version 6 of _gfortran_ should be sufficient, but I'd guess from the compile flags and form of error messages that your `mpif90` is actually passing the compilation to ifort.  I think ifort 16+ (maybe 17) would be required.  You can check the compilation with `mpif90 -show` or similar.

Comment: indeed, and `mpif90` is pointing to ifortran and to a version, which is tool, namely ifort version 14.0.2. I cannot update the version of ifortran, so how can I force mpif90 to point to gfortran?

Comment: There should hopefully be something in the Makefile (or whichever build system creates that) which allows you to change underlying compiler.  You could change `mpif90` to use gfortran instead (often there'll be a flag like `-compiler`) but you'll need to convert the ifort flags to gfortran flags, etc.

Comment: You may also need to recimpile the mpi library for gortran. Ask your system admin if they have mpi for gfortran.

Comment: If this is Intel MPI, the normal default of mpif90 is gfortran. Perhaps your sysadmin renamed the mpif90 and mpiifort, or aliased mpif90 to 'mpif90 -fc=ifort' (but more likely you have some open source mpi built against some version of ifort, so you must heed Vladimir's advice). The MPI Fortran libraries for gfortran and ifort aren't interchangeable, and probably not compatible over such a wide range of major versions.