# What is the difference between use of nested modules and submodules in Fortran?

Tags: module, fortran, fortran2008

I have a module named "mainmodule.f08" and two modules "module1.f08" and "module2.f08". 
In "mainmodule.f08" I have:

```
MODULE mainmodule
    use module1
    use module2
END MODULE mainmodule
```

and I can use the procedures in "module1" and "module2" only stating `use mainmodule` in my programs.

With submodules is possible to do the same thing, but this is much more complex, because I need to redefine on "mainmodule" all procedures in "module1" and "module2" as a interfaces, considering "module1" and "module2" as submodules:

```
MODULE mainmodule
    INTERFACE

       ! Same subroutine from module1.
       subroutine submod1(x)
          integer, intent(in) :: x
       end subroutine submod1

       ! Same function from module2.
       function funcmod2(x) result(y)
          integer, intent(in) :: x
          integer :: y
       end function funcmod2

    END INTERFACE
END MODULE mainmodule
```

Whats is the difference between the two modes of use of the modules if both work in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

These two approaches do not work in the same way.

With

```
MODULE mainmodule
    use module1
    use module2
END MODULE mainmodule
```

the module `mainmodule` makes available the *public* entities in the two other modules.  These are then exposed as public through use association of `mainmodule`.

This is not the same thing as with submodules.

You can read about what submodules *are* with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22825841/3157076).

The end result to the user of the final module may look to be the same, but the details for developers of the modules are significant.