# subroutine using module but is outside module and also used in module through an interface

Tags: fortran

When I have a subroutine outside a module but is used by means of a "pointer assignment" and the subroutine is defined by means of an interface but the real subroutine is in a separate file and used module I get compiler errors.

So when I have the following Fortran code:

```
module test_mod_a
  save

  type test_type_a
    integer :: scl_a = 0
    contains
    procedure :: my_subr => test_subr_a
  end type test_type_a

  interface
    subroutine test_subr_a(this)
      import test_type_a
      implicit none
      class(test_type_a) :: this
    end subroutine test_subr_a
  end interface
end module test_mod_a
```

and

```
subroutine test_subr_a(this)
  use test_mod_a
  implicit none
  class(test_type_a) :: this
end subroutine test_subr_a
```

When I give the commands (gfortran version 9.3.0):

```
gfortran -c test_a.f90
gfortran -c test_a_subr.f90
```

I get the compiler error:

```
test_a_subr.f90:3:6:

    3 |   use test_mod_a
      |      1
Error: ‘test_subr_a’ of module ‘test_mod_a’, imported at (1), is also the name of the current program unit
```

There are a few ways to overcome this problem:

- replace   `!use test_mod_a` by   `!use test_mod_a, only : test_type_a`
- include the subroutine in the module (and discarding in the subroutine the `use` statement and in the module the `interface`

all a bit cumbersome for a large project.

Is there another way?

Comment: It would be helpful to know _why_ `test_subr_a` is an external procedure (or in a separate file). Your suggestion to make the subroutine a module subroutine suggests that isn't required (and makes submodules another option). (I also don't see why `only`, which many would consider good practice anyway, is a problem.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The real problem is that I'm not the original author and the author decided to have the routine outside of the module. The use of `only` is indeed good practice, but might be cumbersome when a lot of entities from a module are used.

Comment: It looks like a horrible hack that one did before submodules addressed the problem of separating implementation from interface (and compilation cascades).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the use of `only` (not including the name of the procedure), there are the two other techniques for avoiding identifier re-use:

- `private test_subr_a` in the module
- Use renaming in the subroutine with `use test_mod_a, self_iface => test_subr_a`

However, from the look of the structure it seems the intention really is for `test_subr_a` to be like a module subroutine but isn't for one of two reasons:

- there's been incremental development of an old program and the external subroutine now wants to be used in a "modern" way
- the implementation of the subroutine is split out for reasons of file size, avoiding compilation cascades, secrecy of implementation

With the luxury of changing the code in a significant way one can handle these.

For the first reason, one could go ahead and move the subroutine into the module and take the pain of having to update other references where it was an external subroutine. As mentioned in the question.

For the second reason, [*submodules*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22825841/3157076) could be considered:

```
module test_mod_a
  implicit none

  type test_type_a
     integer :: scl_a = 0
   contains
     procedure :: my_subr => test_subr_a
  end type test_type_a

  interface
     module subroutine test_subr_a(this)
       class(test_type_a) :: this
     end subroutine test_subr_a
  end interface

end module test_mod_a

submodule(test_mod_a) implementation_a
  implicit none
  
contains

  module subroutine test_subr_a(this)
    class(test_type_a) :: this
  end subroutine test_subr_a

end submodule implementation_a
```

Again, `test_subr_a` is no longer an external subroutine, so other references may need fixing.

Comment: I tested all methods (my only, subroutine in module, private possibility, renaming with self_iface and submodule and in the example I have they all work).